# jQuery windows scroll event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I create the single page.

I want to change CSS when scroll event is active.

So, I tried it with code like this:

```js
var $navscroll = $('nav.nav-next');
$(document).scroll(function() {
  alert($(this).scrollTop()); 
  $navscroll.css({left: $(this).scrollTop()>10 ? "65%":"35%"});
});
```

```css
.nav-next {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-next">
  <button type="button" id="btn-next" class="btn i-down" style="background: rgb(10, 49, 80);">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="10" viewBox="0 0 16 10" enable-background="new 0 0 16 10" xml:space="preserve" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><polygon points="14 0 8 6 2 0 0 2 8 10 16 2 "></polygon></svg>
    <span class="btn-bg btn-bg-mask" style="background: rgb(10, 49, 80);"></span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

But when I tried to scroll it not happen anything.

Comment: is not `$(window).scroll()`? I think the firing element is `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes are working fine but you need to add `height` to your `html body` tag to scroll and see the output of moving that `image`, as below.

```
body{
  height:1200px;
}
```

```js
var $navscroll = $('nav.nav-next');
$(document).on('scroll',function() {
  alert($(this).scrollTop()); 
  $navscroll.css({left: $(this).scrollTop()>10 ? "65%":"35%"});
});
```

```css
.nav-next {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 60%;
}
body{
  height:1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-next">
  <button type="button" id="btn-next" class="btn i-down" style="background: rgb(10, 49, 80);">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="10" viewBox="0 0 16 10" enable-background="new 0 0 16 10" xml:space="preserve" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><polygon points="14 0 8 6 2 0 0 2 8 10 16 2 "></polygon></svg>
    <span class="btn-bg btn-bg-mask" style="background: rgb(10, 49, 80);"></span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: I was using fullpage.js. I can't set a height of the body. It auto generate like: `style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;"`

Comment: Why do you want to trigger something on scroll if your page doesn't have scroll anyways? there might be an easier way achieving your goal?

Comment: You can see full code at pen: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/RoyJOd . I tried to change a position of a button when a user scrolls.

Comment: @vanloc Okay but you should have added that you are using fullpage.js in your question.This is how you could achieve that normally. But will update on this soon.

Comment: @frnt I create a new question at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030625/jquery-windows-scroll-event-not-working-in-fullpage-js Can you help me? Pls...

Comment: @vanloc I have come-up with a solution, hope that help check that on another question posted by you.

Answer (score 1):

Its because that page don't have sufficient height to scroll. Increase page height or container height to allow `scroll`. Check snippet.

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set
>   to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less
>   than the height or width of its contents).

```js
var $navscroll = $('nav.nav-next');
$(document).scroll(function() {
 alert($(this).scrollTop()); 
  $navscroll.css({left: $(this).scrollTop()>10 ? "65%":"35%"});
});
```

```css
.nav-next {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 60%;
}

div {
background: #000;
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-next">
 <button type="button" id="btn-next" class="btn i-down" style="background: rgb(10, 49, 80);">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="10" viewBox="0 0 16 10" enable-background="new 0 0 16 10" xml:space="preserve" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><polygon points="14 0 8 6 2 0 0 2 8 10 16 2 "></polygon></svg>
  <span class="btn-bg btn-bg-mask" style="background: rgb(10, 49, 80);"></span>
 </button>
  
</nav>
<div> test scroll</div>
```

Comment: I using fullpage.js. I can't set height of body or create a div.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest triggering the scroll even on window as opposed to document.

So something like this:
`$(window).scroll(..)`

Also generally wrap your code in:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your Code
});`

to make sure all your elements are available when you select them.